# How to draw a 3D surface plot with numerical datas on matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, surface, mupad

I want to draw a surface on matlab with numerical datas like :

`f(x,y,z) = w`

- f(1,3,5) = 12
- f(2,4,6)= 3
- f(3,8,12)= 2
- f(2,13,22)= 1

and etc...

i found `plot::matrixplot` on mupad but it has two problems :

- first it's on mupad but i want something that do the same on script environment
- second it draw only these types of data : `f(x,y)=z`

sample of mupad :

```
A := [[2, 1, 1],
  [3, 4, 3],
  [3, 5, 4],
  [2, 6, 5]]:
plot(plot::Matrixplot(A))
```

[sample of plot::matrixplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ocDv8.png)

Comment: `f(x,y,z) = w` is not a surface. `z=f(x,y)` is. But if you had a surface, `surf()` will do

Comment: Give a try to [`scatteredInterpolant(x,y,z,v)`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/scatteredinterpolant.html#bvkm1tv-6), then use the [`isosurface()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isosurface.html) to plot the surface.